# ARCore changing pawn model to something else

Tags: java, android, model, arcore

I have been trying to modify sample ar core java application (hello_ar_java exactly). Default model is pawn.obj. I have been trying to change it to any different .obj model but it says im out of memory even though the new model is smaller than the default one.
[image: Screen of the error, when trying to change .obj file to a different one]

```java
// Virtual object to render (ARCore pawn)
Texture virtualObjectAlbedoTexture =
     Texture.createFromAsset(
         render,
         "model1/texturka.png",
         Texture.WrapMode.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
         Texture.ColorFormat.SRGB);
Texture virtualObjectPbrTexture =
     Texture.createFromAsset(
         render,
         "model1/bark.jpg",
         Texture.WrapMode.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
         Texture.ColorFormat.LINEAR);

virtualObjectMesh = Mesh.createFromAsset(render, "models/pawn.obj");
```

Code above is supposed to be picking a model to render, but the last line seems to be giving me errors when i change it to eg.

`virtualObjectMesh = Mesh.createFromAsset(render, "models/square.obj");`

I hope someone had the same problem before and knows how to solve it.

Comment: It's generally better to post the text of the error message in your question as well and not have it in a picture

Comment: Is the square obj is really just a square? I'm asking because if you browse 3D object repositories you notice that there are AR/VR optimized models which basically means that they have as reduced number of vertexes / polygons as possible. AR/VR is a resource restricted environment, you need to spare the polygons. Do you have a URL to your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the .obj file first, did you export it by yourself? Cause there are many different settings with those kind of files:

1 - maybe your model's faces have 4 vertices (square) instead of 3 (triangles) like the pawn model,
2 - or maybe you didn't set a texture in your .obj file and that create conflict with the shader.

You can just open it with an editor and check how many numbers there are after the "f", if there are 4 number that's the problem, it has square faces, you can open it in Blender and in the export settings check "triangle faces" option. You can also add textures in a couple of minutes, and import them in your project.

I hope this helps you, have a nice day!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you optimize your model to have as few vertexes and polygons as possible. When you browse 3D model websites you may notice that AR/VR optimized models are marked, and that basically means extremely reduced vertex / polygon count.

You can model a map location pin object with 156 vertexes and also with 900 vertexes. There are various tools which can take an existing model and algorithmically reduce the polygon count by eliminating and merging vertexes.

Story time: when I was a CAD software developer a customer complained that one of the projects crashed and the computer ran out of memory. After debugging we realized that the house the customer was modeling contained many chandeliers. The chandeliers were hanging from the ceiling via chain. The customer created the chain by taking an extremely detailed high polygon count chain link, copy-pasted that chain link to form the whole chain. Then copy pasted the chandelier. The chandelier light fixture / crystal portion was also high polygon count. This lead to an unfathomable count of polygon and brought down the computer to it's knees in no time.